# How to use correct lang parameter?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki

I have a fresh Mediawiki installed into fresh UBUNTU 18 LTS... The [''SyntaxHighlight'' extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight) not works for [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), `lang="sh"`, `lang="shell"`, `lang="bash"`, ... no one is working. It is not at [#Supported_languages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Supported_languages), and there are no clues about how to install "Other markup".

At [mediawiki.org/list](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Pages_with_syntax_highlighting_errors) there are no clues.

**So, how to solve the problem?** It is a config, env or syntax problem?

---

### NOTES AND TESTS

Notes.

- It is a corporative Wiki, no way to offer public URL... But it is a fresh, standard and controlled installation, all reproductive and standard.
- The Wiki was configured with *skin* "Vector" and *language* "Brazilian Portuguese".

Tests.

1. [Usage tests of mediawiki.org/Extension:SyntaxHighlight](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Usage), the Python example.

   1.1. With tag `<syntaxhighlight>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

   1.2. With tag `<source>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.
2. PHP example, fragment from [wikipedia.org/PHP Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Syntax).

   2.1. With tag `<syntaxhighlight>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

   2.2. With tag `<source>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

The code fragments used in the tests:

```python
def quickSort(arr):
    less = []
    pivotList = []
    more = []
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
        pass
```

```php
<title>PHP "Hello, World!" program</title>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

Comment: Does it work for other languages, say PHP? I confirm you that "shell" is a supported lang.

Comment: Hi @IRA1777, thanks, I edited, see my "NOTES AND TESTS".

Comment: Se also the basic question, and perhaps real solution, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57515213/287948

Answer (score 1):

The use of Pygments in the syntax highlighting extension introduces a dependency that may not be clear in the documentation:  you must have a working python3 installation in the path!  There are two Python programs in the extensions/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi directory: pygmentize and create_pygmentize_bundle.  Both contain the following 'shebang' line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Both files should be executable (e.g. mode 755 rather than 644).  And you should have python3 on the path in the environment the wiki code runs in.
If either of those conditions aren't met in your installation, the result can be exactly the symptoms you're describing: the code blocks look like preformatted text without the syntax coloring.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki Syntax highlighter used Pygments library, you should first download and install the extension:

> Requirements

This version of the extension has been tested with Pygments 1.6, 2.0.2 and
MediaWiki 1.25 as of 2015-06-19. To get releases of this extension compatible
with earlier versions of MediaWiki, visit:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi

> Download

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi/archive/master.tar.gz

> Installation

Add this line to your LocalSettings.php:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
```

By default, this extension will use a bundled copy of Pygments 2.0.2. If you
would like to use a different copy of the library, you can set
$wgPygmentizePath to point to the path to the 'pygmentize' binary.

> Usage

On the wiki page, you can now use "source" elements:

```
<source lang="php">
<?php
    v = "string";    // sample initialization
?>
html text
<?php
    echo v;         // end of php code
?>
</source>
```

> Parameters

For details information of these parameters, see the documentation of Pygments'
HtmlFormatter at http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#HtmlFormatter.

- lang;     Defines the language.
- line;     Corresponds to linenos="inline" option.
- start;    Corresponds to linenostart opion.
- enclose;  If set to "none", corresponds to the nowrap=1 option.
- inline;   Corresponds to the nowrap=1 option.
- highlight;    Corresponds to hl_lines option (comma separated).

> Note

Pygments is generous about creating HTML elements: highlighting large blocks of
code can easily generate enough of them to crash a browser. As a guard, syntax
highlighting is turned off for code fragments larger than 100 kB.

Comment: Hi Mehdi, thanks. It is very difficult to see where the error, but is easy to see that is not working... To use a step-by-step I splitted the question into 2 parts: **P1**) confirm correct instalation and basic working; **P2**) solution to `lang="sh"`.  The P1 can be answered also [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57515213/287948).. And your answer seems about P1.

Comment: Focus in P1, instalation. You copy/paste instructions in your text but not answer what is wrong in the standard instruction that I used with fresh system. Please read my steps and results, please say whats is wrong on my standard procedure. Plase say why I can see it at `Especial:Version` page the "SyntaxHighlight 2.0" (it is installed!). How to check where the bug if there is a software installed and no error message.

Comment: Note: you will get the bounty if solve P1 here, was a kind of  "bounty syncronization" problem, because started before the split. I will correct all question-texts after bounty.