# How to enable the SyntaxHighlight extension after installed?

Tags: mediawiki, syntax-highlighting

I have a fresh Mediawiki (v1.33) installed into fresh UBUNTU 18 LTS... The [''SyntaxHighlight'' extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight) **is not working**, the effect is like a code into `<pre>` tags.

At [mediawiki.org/list](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Pages_with_syntax_highlighting_errors) there are no clues. I used the syntax_highlighting checkbox during Mediawiki installation, and I can see it at `Especial:Version` page as "SyntaxHighlight   2.0", so, it is installed... But is not working.

---

### NOTES AND TESTS

Notes.

- It is a corporative Wiki, no way to offer public URL... But it is a fresh, standard and controlled installation, all reproductive and standard.
- The Wiki was configured with *skin* "Vector" and *language* "Brazilian Portuguese".

Tests.

1. [Usage tests of mediawiki.org/Extension:SyntaxHighlight](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Usage), the Python example.

   1.1. With tag `<syntaxhighlight>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

   1.2. With tag `<source>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.
2. PHP example, fragment from [wikipedia.org/PHP Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Syntax).

   2.1. With tag `<syntaxhighlight>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

   2.2. With tag `<source>`. Result: no highlight, same as `<pre>`.

The code fragments used in the tests:

```python
def quickSort(arr):
    less = []
    pivotList = []
    more = []
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
        pass
```

```php
<title>PHP "Hello, World!" program</title>
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

---

**NOTE2: IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

This question is similar but not same as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297288/287948): here is about the basic "Hello World" of the extension, for any `lang`, and the other is about an specific `lang` installation. We need to solver first here, them, solve the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use correct lang parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297288/how-to-use-correct-lang-parameter)

Comment: Hi @MehdiYeganeh, thanks. They are similar but not same. This question here is only about **basic installation and basic use**, like an "Hello World!" of the extension. The other is about `lang="sh"`. I splitted in two after see that is very difficult to discover where the bug, as MediaWiki say no error message but it is not producing the correct results.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. i upvoted back for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That is because syntaxhighlight in >MediaWiki 1.31 requires Python.
[https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Installation][1]
Besides I am looking for how to install python in a2hosted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).